# 2 tables with the same id

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have 2 tables in the database, first table is userregistration and 2nd table is userdetails. In table userregistration, the primary key that I use is called id and it is auto increment.

So let's say I have insert one user and the id of the user is 1, and then I want to insert the details of the said user, how do I make sure the id is also the same as in the userregistration table?

Already read about last_insert_id, but I can't understand how to use it.

Comment: You can create a relational database something like userregistration and userdetails combined. The userregisteration's id will be passed to userregisteration table as a foreign key for relation. I hope you've read about relational databases.

Comment: It sounds like you are setting up 1:1 tables. A good way to do that is to make the first one a auto-incrementing primary key, and then the second one just a primary key with no auto-increment. Use `last_insert_id` to copy the PK from one to the other when you do your second insert.

Comment: If it is the case of 1:1 maybe there is no reason for the 2nd table to exist at all. Do you have any reasons for not storing the details of the user inside the users table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$server_name = ""; //Your server name
$user_name = ""; //Database Username
$password = ""; //Database Password
$database_name = ""; //Database Name

// Create a connection
$connnection = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $password, $database_name);

//Insert into First Table
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_registration (firstname, lastname)
VALUES ('Firstname', 'Lastname')";

if ($connection->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    $last_inserted_id = $connection->insert_id;
    //Insert into Second Table
    $sql_two = "INSERT INTO user_registration (user_id, phone_no, address)
    VALUES ($last_inserted_id, 1234567, 'Address')";
    $connection->query($sql_two);
}
```

You must create a Foreign key reference in the second table. In this user_id is the Foreign Key.

Comment: This is not bad, but the string concatenation teaches some bad habits. That would be better as a prepare/execute.

Comment: Those SQL queries won't work. They both have an extra `;` after the column list and before `VALUES`;